# Cannot run XUnit with two test projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xunit

I'm using VS 2015 Update 1 with XUnit 2.1.0 and Xunit Runner Visual Studio 2.1.0.

The target is to test my class library project with two  test projects.

    `MyProject
    MyProject.UnitTests
    MyProject.IntegrationTests`

If I just have one test project everything works fine and all tests are run.

    `------ Run test started ------
    [xUnit.net 00:00:00.6855560]   Discovering: MyProject.UnitTests
    [xUnit.net 00:00:01.9601442]   Discovered:  MyProject.UnitTests
    [xUnit.net 00:00:02.5943118]   Starting:    MyProject.UnitTests
    [xUnit.net 00:00:06.8965144]   Finished:    MyProject.UnitTests
    ========== Run test finished: 171 run (0:00:12.8197155) ==========`

If I add the second test project xUnit failes with following error message:

    `------ Run test started ------
    [xUnit.net 00:00:00.4755152]   Discovering: MyProject.IntegrationTests
    [xUnit.net 00:00:00.8076825]   Discovered:  MyProject.IntegrationTests
    [xUnit.net 00:00:01.2465443]   Discovering: MyProject.UnitTests
    [xUnit.net 00:00:02.0314670]   Discovered:  MyProject.UnitTests
    [xUnit.net 00:00:02.4066592]   Starting:    MyProject.IntegrationTests
    The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. The test execution process crashed while running the tests. To investigate further, open file:///C:/Users/Ben/AppData/Local/CrashDumps/TE.ProcessHost.Managed.exe.14520.dmp file in Visual Studio and choose "Debug in mixed mode".
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:17.8042124) ==========`

The crash dump file just says

    `Exception Code: 0xc0000fd
    Exception Information: The thread used up its stack.
    Heap information: not present`

If I start Debug in mixed mode nothing happens.

I think it is any race condition of xUnit if I have two test projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems here to be an unfortunate error message.
My library occures an exception due one theory configuration.

This exception obviously suprises xUnit and you get this Error. I've fixed the exception handling and the error is done end everything works fine.